# error message missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement

I am getting the following error message:

> Error in if (abs(p11_p10) < 1e-04 & abs(alpha1_alpha0) < 1e-04) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I am trying to do simulation and estimation and for that I have written the below program:

```
p1=0.2;p2=0.3;p3=1-p1-p2;alpha=0.4
n=10;k=1;count=0
p11_p10=0.01
alpha1_alpha0=0.01
alpha0=0.5;p10=0.3;p11_p10=0.1;alpha1_alpha0=0.1
repeat
{
    repeat
    {
        x1<-rgeom(n-k,p3/(1-p2))
        y1<-rnbinom(n-k,x1+1,1-p2)
        p3star<-1-alpha*p1-alpha*p2
        xstar<-rgeom(k,p3star/(1-alpha*p2))
        ystar<-rnbinom(k,xstar+1,1-alpha*p2)
        xsamp<-c(x1,xstar)
        ysamp<-c(y1,ystar)
        x=rep(0,n)
        y=rep(0,n)
        z=rep(0,n)
        for(i in 1:n)
        {  
            x[i]=(xsamp[i]+ysamp[i])*(alpha0^(xsamp[i]+ysamp[i]-1))
            y[i]=alpha0^(xsamp[i]+ysamp[i])
            z[i]=((xsamp[i]+ysamp[i])*(xsamp[i]+ysamp[i]-1)*
            (alpha0^(xsamp[i]+ysamp[i]-2)))
        }
        x;y;z
        num=sum(x)
        den=sum(y)
        num1=sum(z)

        term=num1/den
        if(term>0)
        {
            T1<-sum(xsamp); T2<-sum(ysamp)
            if (T1!=0 || T2!=0)
            {
                break   
            }
        }
    }
    print(T1)
    print(T2)
    count=0
    repeat      
    {
        count=count+1
        b1=(k/n)
        A=alpha0*(((T1+T2)^2)+n*(T1+T2))
        B=(-T1*((alpha0+1)*(T1+T2)+(n+alpha0-1)))
        C=(T1^2)

        t1_p1_alpha<-A*(p10^2)+(B*p10)+C
        t2_p1_alpha= -((p10*(T1+T2))/(T1-alpha0*(T1+T2)*p10))+(num/den)

        t1dash_wrt_p1=2*A*p10+B
        t1dash_wrt_alpha=(p10^2)*((T1+T2)^2)+n*(p10^2)*(T1+T2)-p10*T1*(T1+T2+1)

        t2dash_wrt_p1=(((-T1*(T1+T2))/(T1-alpha0*(T1+T2)*p10))^2)
        t2dash_wrt_alpha= (-((p10*(T1+T2))^2)/((T1-alpha0*(T1+T2)*p10)^2))+(num1/den)-((num^2)/(den^2))

        a<-t1_p1_alpha;b<-t1dash_wrt_p1;c<-t1dash_wrt_alpha
        d<-t2_p1_alpha;e<-t2dash_wrt_p1;f<-t2dash_wrt_alpha

        alpha1=alpha0+(1/c)*(-a-b*((a*f-d*c)/(e*c-b*f)))
        p11=p10+((a*f-d*c)/(e*c-b*f))
        p11_p10=p11-p10

        alpha1_alpha0<-alpha1-alpha0

        if(abs(p11_p10)<0.0001 & abs(alpha1_alpha0)<0.0001)
        {   
            break
            print(p11)
            print(alpha1)
        }
        else
        {
            p10<-p11
            alpha0<-alpha1
        }
        if (count>50){break}    
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the assessed values is probably not a number and `abs` returns `NA`.

Comment: Try putting parentheses `()` around each expression either side of the `&` - it might not be evaluating that if statement in the order you expect.

Comment: I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: I ran the code and you are getting some `NaN` values that seem to be caused by a divide-by-zero in the calculation of `t2dash_wrt_p1`.

Comment: After adding condition that denominator is not equal to zero, I am getting same error message.